# Drunken dancer. Best fit of an experimental trajectory to model trajectories with large variations in independent variable

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have several model point trajectories (choreographies), describing movement of a model dancer in a one (for simplicity) dimensional space versus time. I am also observing a movement of a real drunken dancer, who "tries" to follow one of the model trajectories (we don't know which one). The task is to find which model trajectory the drunken dancer is trying to follow. (Classification problem)

The complication is that in addition to the errors in an observed position, the drunken dancer can move faster or slower compared to a model trajectory at any given time.

If not for the latter variations in the rate of the independent variable, this would be solved by selecting a model trajectory, which is characterized by a minimum distance to the experimental trajectory. However the variation of the drunkard's speed compared to the model trajectory must be taken into account.

How can I select a best model trajectory (guess which dance is being danced by the drunkard), taking into account the unknown variation in the drunkard's speed, in R, or using any other means?

Thanks.

Comment: Own Answer. Errors in independent variables are handled by Total Least Squares, in regression fitting. In the Drunken Dancer case, calculating the distance will suffice. From this discussion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares, this problem should be solved accounting for the difference in the measurement units of dependent and independent variables. Further the reference to a paper Model Fitting for Multiple Variables by Minimising the Geometric Mean Deviation http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1077322 produces a suitable measure -- geometric mean deviation.